# Changing default Home application in android without user interaction

Tags: android

Is there any way to make it so my app can set itself as the default Home app without any user interaction?

Answer (score 1):

Nope.  It would be a security risk to allow apps to take over without the user allowing it.

Comment: But, what about the Home Switcher app?  It doesn't do the normal way of asking the user to select a default.  The app could potentially set which ever one it wanted.

Comment: It still requires the user to choose to set that app as the default.

Comment: Yes, but that's the app itself asking.  Not the regular prompt that the android OS or whatever does.  So it should be possible for that app to just ignore what the user selects and always choose some other thing.